# how to remove symbol and do math

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I have a simple app which insert data and should do the math, but here is the problem. I USE UITextFiled to insert data (prices) into UILabels, but my data includes dollar sign, and when I use this code:

```
 _total.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%i", [_lastPrice1.text intValue] +    [_lastPrice2.text intValue] +[_lastPrice3.text intValue] + [_lastPrice4.text intValue] + [_lastPrice5.text intValue] + [_lastPrice6.text intValue] ];
```

**To do the total, it doesn't work. If I insert data without dollar sign, then the above code works great.**

Any Ideas how to do fix it ?

Comment: I have ONE UITextField. I use it to insert prices with dollar sign (Ex.: $187) into UILabels. I have 6 UILabels. So, when I'm done with inserting prices, all my labels looks like: $187 $289 $40 $987 $123 $589 Everything is good so far. Now, I want to sum all these numbers from UILabels, so I use the above code. I doesn't work because of dollar sign in front of price. Any ideas how to fix it? I want to keep this dollar sign. Thanks.

Comment: check the answer for **$** and **,** condition

Comment: @RaduRomanov Please stop using so much UPPERCASE. If you need emphasis, you can make text **bold** or *italic*. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this to remove **$** sign

```
[[_lastPrice1.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@""] intValue];
```

Comment: WHAT if my price is decimal: $128,76 ?

Comment: then use floatValue instead of intValue, and replace the comma with dot

Comment: @ÐąrέÐέvil replacing comma with dot will not work. **$1,000 is not equal to 1.000. It is equal to 1000**

Answer (score 2):

You could use the method

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target 
                                        withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

to get a new string with a substring replaced (See [`NSString`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW25) documentation for others)

**How to use?**

```
NSString *str = @"This is a simple string replacement technique";

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"technique"
                                     withString:@"method"];
```

**In Your case: $ and ,**

```
 [[[_lastPrice1.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""] intValue];
```

Comment: @radu-romanov ÐąrέÐέvil solution will fail if replacing comma with dot. $1,000 is not equal to 1.000. It is equal to 1000

Comment: @radu-romanov Is the above solution not working for you? Earlier you had accept the answer and then unaccepted it. My solution will take care of **$** and **,** conditions which is what you needed.